# Parallel for loop in Swift

Tags: parallel-processing, swift

What is the closest Swift equivalent of the following C & OpenMP code (assume that `n` is huge and `f` is simple):

```
#openmp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    a[i] = f(b[i]);
}
```

Parallelising a for loop with striding and `dispatch_apply` seems like a lot of work for such a routine task. Is there any clever shortcut?

Comment: Maybe you need to use the other Swift: http://swift-lang.org/

Comment: right, using java for high performance,  swift-lang.org.....  uhm no

Answer (score 9):

If your code has loops, and the work being done each time through the loop is independent of the work being done in the other iterations, you might consider reimplementing that loop code using the dispatch_apply or dispatch_apply_f function. These functions submit each iteration of a loop separately to a dispatch queue for processing. When used in conjunction with a concurrent queue, this feature lets you perform multiple iterations of the loop concurrently.

Read here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW2

For swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1000) { (index) in
     print("current: \(index)")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears (from the iBook) that there's not yet a swift-specific API/language feature for parallelism. Using GCD seems like the best option at this point, performance-wise. If you're looking for code brevity, you can just use the standard Objective-C idiom for concurrent array enumeration:

```
    var array : Int[] = [1,2,3,4]
    array.bridgeToObjectiveC().enumerateObjectsWithOptions(NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent, {(obj: AnyObject!, index: Int, outStop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        // Do stuff
    });
```

Comment: I'd be very interested to see benchmarks comparing this kind of approach with (1) a straightforward single-threaded Swift implementation, and (2) an OpenMP-parallelised C implementation!

Comment: If the single threaded swift implementation outperforms OpenMP then the workload was a bad candidate for parallelization in the first place. If the OpenMP version outperforms the single threaded swift, well... it's not surprising, really. I think the more interesting comparison would be swift using GCD for parallelism vs C using OpenMP. (And I would expect that for sufficiently parallel workloads, C would win, but it'd be an interesting test.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I would like to see two different comparisons: (1) Swift NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent parallelism vs. Swift single-threaded and (2) Swift NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent parallelism vs. C OpenMP parallelism.

Comment: w/r/t #1, my comment stands. Single threaded vs. parallel is uninteresting no matter what API is used, because it should be completely dominated by the question of how parallel the workload is in the first place.

Comment: No, I think benchmarking (1) is very important in order to learn if we can achieve near-optimal speedups with NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent parallelism in Swift applications. I am not at all convinced that the overhead related to the implementation of enumerateObjectsWithOptions(NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent) is negligible, especially if you need to bridge between Swift and ObjC. With C & OpenMP it is well-known that you can achieve near-optimal speedups (e.g., with 20 cores you can get almost 20-fold speedups in comparison with a single-threaded version); is this the case with Swift, too?

Answer (score 2):

For parallelism of `for` loop in Swift, you must use

`DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iteration: execute:)`

Answer (score 1):

The clue in above answer about using `concurrentPerform` is correct, but not expanded. So here's the simples solution:

```
class ConcurrentCalculator<T> {

    func calc(for b: [T], _ f: (T) -> T) -> [T?] {

        let n = b.count

        var a: [T?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: n)

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: n) { i in

            a[i] = f(b[i])
        }

        return a
    }
}
```

And here's the test:

```
let myB = Array(1...100)

func myF(b: Int) -> Int {

    b * b
}

let myCalc = ConcurrentCalculator<Int>()
let myA = myCalc.calc(for: myB, myF)

print(myA)
```

The output will look like

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000]
```

Of course this is a basic solution: it's not thread safe, and also it may run into memory issues with large arrays. This can be added later.

The beauty of this approach is that you don't need to count available threads, etc. It will just use all available threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Swift array to `NSArray` and use `enumerateObjectsWithOptions` without bridging - see simple example below:

```
let kCompanyListFileNames :[String] = [
  "nyse_companylist",
  "nasdaq_companylist",
  "amex_companylist"
]

let companyListFileNames:NSArray = kCompanyListFileNames as NSArray

companyListFileNames.enumerateObjectsWithOptions(NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent) {
      (companyName:AnyObject!, index:Int, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
      println(companyName)
    }
```

Comment: do you realize how much of a kludge this solution looks like to someone who is used to high peformance c or fortran?  no way to take swift serioiusly with openmp, mpi or other high performance parallel computing lib built-in.  i'll keep my openmp pragmas and use the ridiculous bridging header.

Comment: @μολὼν.λαβέ At the same time, Swift & the Swift community are well aware that Swift isn't meant as the end-all and be-all solution for every programming problem.  Swift has a lot of bridging to it's predecessor, Objective-C, but arguably even more effort has been put into bridging to plain-C by importing C data types and functions into Swift cleanly.  The sane, intended real-world solution here is to write the performance critical stuff in C, wrap it up in a function, and use that function from Swift.